# Micronaut Vault Config Client gives no bean of type SerdeConfiguration exists error

Tags: micronaut, vault

I want to pull configurations from Vault and got the below error while starting my app by enabling Config Client and Vault. The no SerdeConfiguration bean error happened even before hitting the Vault server.

I wonder whether I missed anything on the bootstrap.yml or was supposed to provide a custom SerdeConfiguration.

```
Message: No bean of type [io.micronaut.serde.config.SerdeConfiguration] exists. Make sure the bean is not disabled by bean requirements (enable trace logging for 'io.micronaut.context.condition' to check) and if the bean is enabled then ensure the class is declared a bean and annotation processing is enabled (for Java and Kotlin the 'micronaut-inject-java' dependency should be configured as an annotation processor).
Path Taken: 
new DistributedPropertySourceLocator(ConfigurationClient configurationClient,Duration readTimeout)
--> new DistributedPropertySourceLocator([ConfigurationClient configurationClient],Duration readTimeout)
--> new DefaultCompositeConfigurationClient([ConfigurationClient[] configurationClients])
--> new VaultConfigurationClient([VaultConfigHttpClient configHttpClient],VaultClientConfiguration vaultClientConfiguration,ApplicationConfiguration applicationConfiguration,ExecutorService executorService)
--> new VaultConfigHttpClientV1$Intercepted(BeanResolutionContext $beanResolutionContext,BeanContext $beanContext,Qualifier $qualifier,[List $interceptors])
--> new HttpClientIntroductionAdvice([HttpClientRegistry clientFactory],JsonMediaTypeCodec jsonMediaTypeCodec,List transformers,HttpClientBinderRegistry binderRegistry,ConversionService conversionService)
--> new DefaultNettyHttpClientRegistry(HttpClientConfiguration defaultHttpClientConfiguration,HttpClientFilterResolver httpClientFilterResolver,LoadBalancerResolver loadBalancerResolver,NettyClientSslBuilder nettyClientSslBuilder,ThreadFactory threadFactory,MediaTypeCodecRegistry codecRegistry,EventLoopGroupRegistry eventLoopGroupRegistry,EventLoopGroupFactory eventLoopGroupFactory,BeanContext beanContext,List invocationInstrumenterFactories,[JsonMapper jsonMapper])
--> new JacksonJsonMapper([SerdeRegistry registry])
--> new DefaultSerdeRegistry(BeanContext beanContext,[ObjectSerializer objectSerializer],ObjectDeserializer objectDeserializer,Serde objectArraySerde,SerdeIntrospections introspections)
--> new ObjectSerializer([SerdeIntrospections introspections],SerializationConfiguration configuration)
--> new DefaultSerdeIntrospections([SerdeConfiguration configuration])
io.micronaut.context.exceptions.DependencyInjectionException: Failed to inject value for parameter [configuration] of class: io.micronaut.serde.support.DefaultSerdeIntrospections
```

Below is my **bootstrap.yml**

```
micronaut:
  application:
    name: my-app
  config-client:
    enabled: true 

vault:
  client:
    uri: http://localhost:8200
    token: hvs.ugHfHLMdA3PBJT6K2GjVdJZ4
    kv-version: V1 
    config:
      enabled: true
```

I tried adding micronaut.serde.* configurations on the bootstrap.yml with hoping SerdeConfiguration is injected, but saw no difference.

Below link shows possible SerdeConfiguration user can setup though.
https://micronaut-projects.github.io/micronaut-serialization/latest/guide/configurationreference.html

Here the Micronaut version and the maven compiler plugin setup I have

```
    <parent>
        <groupId>io.micronaut</groupId>
        <artifactId>micronaut-parent</artifactId>
        <version>3.8.3</version>
    </parent>

    <properties>
        <packaging>jar</packaging>
        <jdk.version>17</jdk.version>
        <release.version>17</release.version>
        <micronaut.version>3.8.3</micronaut.version>
        <micronaut.runtime>netty</micronaut.runtime>
        <micronaut.data.version>3.9.4</micronaut.data.version>
        <micronaut.security.version>3.9.2</micronaut.security.version>
        <micronaut.serialization.version>1.5.0</micronaut.serialization.version>
                     :


  <plugin>
      <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
      <artifactId>maven-compiler-plugin</artifactId>
      <configuration>
          <annotationProcessorPaths combine.children="append">
              <path>
                  <groupId>org.projectlombok</groupId>
                  <artifactId>lombok</artifactId>
                  <version>${lombok.version}</version>
              </path>
              <path>
                  <groupId>io.micronaut</groupId>
                  <artifactId>micronaut-inject-java</artifactId>
                  <version>${micronaut.version}</version>
              </path>
              <path>
                  <groupId>io.micronaut.data</groupId>
                  <artifactId>micronaut-data-processor</artifactId>
                  <version>${micronaut.data.version}</version>
              </path>
              <path>
                  <groupId>io.micronaut</groupId>
                  <artifactId>micronaut-graal</artifactId>
                  <version>${micronaut.version}</version>
              </path>
              <path>
                  <groupId>io.micronaut</groupId>
                  <artifactId>micronaut-http-validation</artifactId>
                  <version>${micronaut.version}</version>
              </path>
              <path>
                  <groupId>io.micronaut</groupId>
                  <artifactId>micronaut-validation</artifactId>
                  <version>${micronaut.version}</version>
              </path>
              <path>
                  <groupId>io.micronaut.data</groupId>
                  <artifactId>micronaut-data-r2dbc</artifactId>
                  <version>${micronaut.data.version}</version>
              </path>
              <path>
                  <groupId>io.micronaut</groupId>
                  <artifactId>micronaut-http-client-core</artifactId>
                  <version>${micronaut.version}</version>
              </path>
              <path>
                  <groupId>io.micronaut.discovery</groupId>
                  <artifactId>micronaut-discovery-client</artifactId>
                  <version>3.2.0</version>
              </path>
              <path>
                  <groupId>io.micronaut.serde</groupId>
                  <artifactId>micronaut-serde-processor</artifactId>
                  <version>${micronaut.serialization.version}</version>
              </path>
              <path>
                  <groupId>io.micronaut.serde</groupId>
                  <artifactId>micronaut-serde-api</artifactId>
                  <version>${micronaut.serialization.version}</version>
              </path>
              <path>
                  <groupId>io.micronaut.security</groupId>
                  <artifactId>micronaut-security-annotations</artifactId>
                  <version>${micronaut.security.version}</version>
              </path>
          </annotationProcessorPaths>
          <compilerArgs>
              <arg>-Amicronaut.processing.group=com.test</arg>
              <arg>-Amicronaut.processing.module=my-app</arg>
          </compilerArgs>
      </configuration>
  </plugin>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The resolution of this issue was achieved through a straightforward upgrade to Micronaut version 4, with no necessary changes in the codebase. Following the upgrade, the retrieval and application of database configurations from the Vault proceeded seamlessly.

[ pom.xml ]

```
<parent>
    <groupId>io.micronaut</groupId>
    <artifactId>micronaut-parent</artifactId>
    <version>4.0.0-M1</version>
    <relativePath />
</parent>

<properties>
    <packaging>jar</packaging>
    <jdk.version>17</jdk.version>
    <release.version>17</release.version>
    <micronaut.version>4.0.0-M1</micronaut.version>
    <micronaut.core.version>4.0.0-M1</micronaut.core.version>
    <micronaut.validation.version>4.0.0-M1</micronaut.validation.version>
    <micronaut.serialization.version>2.0.0-M1</micronaut.serialization.version>
    <micronaut.runtime>netty</micronaut.runtime>

                    :
<build>
    <plugins>
        <plugin>
            <groupId>io.micronaut.build</groupId>
            <artifactId>micronaut-maven-plugin</artifactId>
            <configuration>
            </configuration>
        </plugin>
        <plugin>
            <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
            <artifactId>maven-compiler-plugin</artifactId>
            <configuration>
                <release>17</release>
                <annotationProcessorPaths combine.children="append">
                    <path>
                        <groupId>org.projectlombok</groupId>
                        <artifactId>lombok</artifactId>
                        <version>${lombok.version}</version>
                    </path>
                    <path>
                        <groupId>io.micronaut</groupId>
                        <artifactId>micronaut-context</artifactId>
                        <version>${micronaut.version}</version>
                    </path>
                    <path>
                        <groupId>io.micronaut</groupId>
                        <artifactId>micronaut-inject</artifactId>
                        <version>${micronaut.version}</version>
                    </path>
                    <path>
                        <groupId>io.micronaut</groupId>
                        <artifactId>micronaut-inject-java</artifactId>
                        <version>${micronaut.version}</version>
                    </path>
                    <path>
                        <groupId>io.micronaut.validation</groupId>
                        <artifactId>micronaut-validation-processor</artifactId>
                        <version>${micronaut.validation.version}</version>
                    </path>
                    <path>
                        <groupId>io.micronaut.data</groupId>
                        <artifactId>micronaut-data-processor</artifactId>
                        <version>${micronaut.version}</version>
                    </path>
                    <path>
                        <groupId>io.micronaut</groupId>
                        <artifactId>micronaut-graal</artifactId>
                        <version>${micronaut.version}</version>
                    </path>
                    <path>
                        <groupId>io.micronaut</groupId>
                        <artifactId>micronaut-http-validation</artifactId>
                        <version>${micronaut.version}</version>
                    </path>
                    <path>
                        <groupId>io.micronaut.validation</groupId>
                        <artifactId>micronaut-validation</artifactId>
                        <version>${micronaut.version}</version>
                    </path>
                    <path>
                        <groupId>io.micronaut.data</groupId>
                        <artifactId>micronaut-data-r2dbc</artifactId>
                        <version>${micronaut.version}</version>
                    </path>
                    <path>
                        <groupId>io.micronaut</groupId>
                        <artifactId>micronaut-http-client-core</artifactId>
                        <version>${micronaut.version}</version>
                    </path>
                    <path>
                        <groupId>io.micronaut.discovery</groupId>
                        <artifactId>micronaut-discovery-client</artifactId>
                        <version>${micronaut.version}</version>
                    </path>
                    <path>
                        <groupId>io.micronaut.serde</groupId>
                        <artifactId>micronaut-serde-processor</artifactId>
                        <version>${micronaut.serialization.version}</version>
                    </path>
                    <path>
                        <groupId>io.micronaut.serde</groupId>
                        <artifactId>micronaut-serde-api</artifactId>
                        <version>${micronaut.serialization.version}</version>
                    </path>
                    <path>
                        <groupId>io.micronaut.security</groupId>
                        <artifactId>micronaut-security-annotations</artifactId>
                        <version>${micronaut.version}</version>
                    </path>
                </annotationProcessorPaths>
                <compilerArgs>
                    <arg>-Amicronaut.processing.group=com.test</arg>
                    <arg>-Amicronaut.processing.module=my-app</arg>
                </compilerArgs>
            </configuration>
        </plugin>

         :

<dependencies>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>io.micronaut</groupId>
        <artifactId>micronaut-inject</artifactId>
        <scope>compile</scope>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>io.micronaut</groupId>
        <artifactId>micronaut-inject-java</artifactId>
        <scope>compile</scope>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>io.micronaut</groupId>
        <artifactId>micronaut-context</artifactId>
        <scope>compile</scope>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>io.micronaut.validation</groupId>
        <artifactId>micronaut-validation</artifactId>
        <scope>compile</scope>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>io.micronaut</groupId>
        <artifactId>micronaut-http-client</artifactId>
        <scope>compile</scope>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>io.micronaut</groupId>
        <artifactId>micronaut-http-server-netty</artifactId>
        <scope>compile</scope>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>io.micronaut</groupId>
        <artifactId>micronaut-runtime</artifactId>
        <exclusions>
            <exclusion>
                <groupId>io.micronaut</groupId>
                <artifactId>micronaut-jackson-databind</artifactId>
            </exclusion>
        </exclusions>
        <scope>compile</scope>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>io.micronaut.data</groupId>
        <artifactId>micronaut-data-processor</artifactId>
        <scope>compile</scope>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>io.micronaut.data</groupId>
        <artifactId>micronaut-data-r2dbc</artifactId>
        <scope>compile</scope>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>io.micronaut.flyway</groupId>
        <artifactId>micronaut-flyway</artifactId>
        <scope>compile</scope>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>io.micronaut.serde</groupId>
        <artifactId>micronaut-serde-jackson</artifactId>
        <scope>compile</scope>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>io.micronaut.sql</groupId>
        <artifactId>micronaut-jdbc-ucp</artifactId>
        <scope>compile</scope>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>jakarta.annotation</groupId>
        <artifactId>jakarta.annotation-api</artifactId>
        <scope>compile</scope>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>io.micronaut.security</groupId>
        <artifactId>micronaut-security-jwt</artifactId>
        <scope>compile</scope>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>io.micronaut.discovery</groupId>
        <artifactId>micronaut-discovery-client</artifactId>
        <scope>compile</scope>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>io.micronaut</groupId>
        <artifactId>micronaut-management</artifactId>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>io.micronaut</groupId>
        <artifactId>micronaut-retry</artifactId>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>io.micronaut.micrometer</groupId>
        <artifactId>micronaut-micrometer-core</artifactId>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>io.micronaut.micrometer</groupId>
        <artifactId>micronaut-micrometer-registry-statsd</artifactId>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>io.micronaut.micrometer</groupId>
        <artifactId>micronaut-micrometer-registry-jmx</artifactId>
        <scope>compile</scope>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>ch.qos.logback</groupId>
        <artifactId>logback-classic</artifactId>
        <scope>runtime</scope>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>io.r2dbc</groupId>
        <artifactId>r2dbc-pool</artifactId>
    </dependency>

         :
```

[ bootstrap.yml ]

```
micronaut:
  application:
    name: my-app
  config-client:
    enabled: true 
  security:
    enabled: true
    authentication: BEARER
    basic-auth:
      enabled: false
    token:
      enabled: true
      jwt:
        bearer:
          enabled: true
        signatures:
          secret:
            generator:
              secret: secret0123456789
  metrics:
    enabled: true
  binders:
    files:
      enabled: true
    jdbc:
      enabled: true
    jvm:
      enabled: true
    logback:
      enabled: true
    processor:
      enabled: true
    uptime:
      enabled: true
    web:
      enabled: true
  server:
    port: 7777
vault:
  client:
    uri: http://localhost:8200
    token: hvs.kSWIif3OlAHh1SBu1nBCQQ0N
    kv-version: V1
    config:
      enabled: true
```

[ application.yml ]

```
r2dbc:
  datasources:
    default:
      url: ${R2DBC_URL}
      username: ${R2DBC_USERNAME}
      password: ${R2DBC_PASSWORD}
      dialect: ORACLE

datasources:
  default:
    url: ${JDBC_URL}
    username: ${JDBC_USERNAME}
    password: ${JDBC_PASSWORD}
    dialect: ORACLE
    driver-class-name: oracle.jdbc.driver.OracleDriver

flyway:
  datasources:
    default:
      enabled: true
```

[ application log ]

```
12:44:18.218 [main] DEBUG i.m.d.v.c.VaultConfigurationClient - Vault server endpoint: http://localhost:8200, secret engine version: V1, secret-engine-name: secret, vault keys path prefix: 
12:44:18.218 [main] DEBUG i.m.d.v.c.VaultConfigurationClient - Application name: my-app, application profiles: []
            :
12:44:18.503 [default-nioEventLoopGroup-1-2] DEBUG i.m.h.client.netty.DefaultHttpClient - Sending HTTP GET to http://localhost:8200/v1/secret/my-app
12:44:18.505 [default-nioEventLoopGroup-1-2] TRACE i.m.h.client.netty.DefaultHttpClient - X-Vault-Token: *MASKED*
12:44:18.505 [default-nioEventLoopGroup-1-2] TRACE i.m.h.client.netty.DefaultHttpClient - Accept: application/json
12:44:18.505 [default-nioEventLoopGroup-1-2] TRACE i.m.h.client.netty.DefaultHttpClient - host: localhost:8200
12:44:18.505 [default-nioEventLoopGroup-1-2] TRACE i.m.h.client.netty.DefaultHttpClient - connection: keep-alive
            :
12:44:18.524 [default-nioEventLoopGroup-1-2] DEBUG i.m.h.client.netty.DefaultHttpClient - Received response 200 from http://localhost:8200/v1/secret/my-app
12:44:18.525 [default-nioEventLoopGroup-1-2] TRACE i.m.h.client.netty.DefaultHttpClient - HTTP Client Response Received (200 OK) for Request: GET http://localhost:8200/v1/secret/my-app
12:44:18.525 [default-nioEventLoopGroup-1-2] TRACE i.m.h.client.netty.DefaultHttpClient - Cache-Control: no-store
12:44:18.525 [default-nioEventLoopGroup-1-2] TRACE i.m.h.client.netty.DefaultHttpClient - Content-Type: application/json
12:44:18.525 [default-nioEventLoopGroup-1-2] TRACE i.m.h.client.netty.DefaultHttpClient - Strict-Transport-Security: max-age=31536000; includeSubDomains
12:44:18.525 [default-nioEventLoopGroup-1-2] TRACE i.m.h.client.netty.DefaultHttpClient - Date: Wed, 17 Jan 2024 20:44:18 GMT
12:44:18.525 [default-nioEventLoopGroup-1-2] TRACE i.m.h.client.netty.DefaultHttpClient - Content-Length: 510
12:44:18.525 [default-nioEventLoopGroup-1-2] TRACE i.m.h.client.netty.DefaultHttpClient - Response Body
12:44:18.525 [default-nioEventLoopGroup-1-2] TRACE i.m.h.client.netty.DefaultHttpClient - ----
12:44:18.525 [default-nioEventLoopGroup-1-2] TRACE i.m.h.client.netty.DefaultHttpClient - {"request_id":"4c2f3ed3-bf6e-05d4-f91b-9d485b55becf","lease_id":"","renewable":false,"lease_duration":2764800,"data":{"datasources":{"default":{"dialect":"ORACLE","driver-class-name":"oracle.jdbc.driver.OracleDriver","password":"pass","url":"jdbc:oracle:thin:@//localhost:1521/mydb","username":"user123"}},"r2dbc":{"datasources":{"default":{"dialect":"ORACLE","password":"pass","url":"r2dbc:oracle://localhost:1521/mydb","username":"user123"}}}},"wrap_info":null,"warnings":null,"auth":null}
```

Answer (score 0):

This helped me. I added custom Bean to BootstrapContext:

```
@Singleton
@Replaces(SerdeConfiguration.class)
@BootstrapContextCompatible
public class SerdeConfigurationBootstrap implements SerdeConfiguration {

    @Override
    public Optional<String> getDateFormat() {
        return Optional.empty();
    }

    @Override
    public boolean isWriteDatesAsTimestamps() {
        return false;
    }

    @Override
    public Optional<Locale> getLocale() {
        return Optional.empty();
    }

    @Override
    public Optional<TimeZone> getTimeZone() {
        return Optional.empty();
    }

    @Override
    public List<String> getIncludedIntrospectionPackages() {
        return Collections.emptyList();
    }
}
```

Comment: This custom serde config seems to remove the no bean issue but breaks the restful endpoints with the error ```i.m.http.server.RouteExecutor Unexpected error occurred: Error encoding object [Internal Server Error] to JSON: No serializable introspection present for type JsonError.``` The endpoints worked fine before with config from application.yml. After debugging this, I suspect the JsonError is by failing to load configuration from the vault even though the application contacted the vault successfully. I feel this is not the solution since this break all the endpoints.

Comment: @StevePark Did you manage to resolve this issue? I am also experiencing similar issue. I am using com.fasterxml.jackson.core:jackson-databind on top of that would need to use micronaut serialization using micronaut-serde-jackson. Seems both libraries are conflicting.

micronaut.serde.* configurations didn't help in anyway!

Let me know if you found any solution for this issue.